# Memory Utilization for auto scaling group AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

I am Setting up AWS autoscaling, and while setting scaling policy i ran into this problem.

I wanted to use memory as a parameter, so i installed CLoudwatch's script for memory monitoring from below link.

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html

When i use it for simple instance it works fine. but when i do it for autosacling with below command as suggested in above doc it gives error

Command

> ./mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail --auto-scaling=only

Error:

> WARNING: The Auto Scaling metrics will not be reported this time.

when i check this error on internet few people said it may be error of instance-id in /var/tmp/aws-mon i checked that is not the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This can be pretty useful: https://medium.com/@lvthillo/aws-auto-scaling-based-on-memory-utilization-in-cloudformation-159676b6f4d6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well i did the most stupid thing possible in this scenario, i am posting this as an answer so it can help anyone else. 
i was testing on the instance which was not member of any auto scaling group.

Answer (score 7):

Working Solution if your instance belongs to Autoscaling group.

```
rm -rf /var/tmp/aws-mon/
```

Then run,

```
./mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --auto-scaling=only
```

When the monitoring script runs it caches the instance_id under `/var/tmp/aws-mon`.
 One of the filters it uses when getting the auto scaling group name is the instance id. The TTL on this is 6 hours, so if your AMI has this cache, the query will use the wrong instance id for up to 6 hours after the instance is created which results in it failing to retrieve the auto scaling group name.

REF:  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=117783

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=84514) is link to AWS support with same question.

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/code/amazon-cloudwatch-monitoring-scripts-for-linux/) is link to source code of the Perl script. I'm not sure if it can be publicated here, so open the ZIP file go to `mon-put-instance-data.pl`, and search for `reported`. From that to ifs it appear that the error occurs if you did not provided `verify`, nor autoscaling group name. Since first is only for testing - we have winner. Please provide autoscaling group name parameter...

Well, there are no that parameter, but if you look closer you can see that some lines before `reported` from find, there is query for that. So... your instance has no access.

Googling with `CloudWatchClient::get_auto_scaling_group` gives this [result](https://serverfault.com/questions/532675/which-permissions-policies-for-iam-role-to-be-used-with-cloudwatch-monitoring-sc). From there you can read that you should grant your instance permission to publish data to CloudWatch...

If you have other questions, please - ask. I'll edit this answer, so we will have something more or less complete - not only for me.

Comment: thnks for the effort , i found out the reason and update as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same challenge, but the correct answer to this question is, you might have missed the prerequisites which are mentioned at:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html#mon-scripts-
perl_prereq

This compilation error actually shows that there are some packages missing, which are required to run the perl script.

If you are using EC2 linux instance to run these scripts, you  have probably missed running following command:

```
sudo yum install -y perl-Switch perl-DateTime perl-Sys-Syslog perl-LWP-Protocol-https perl-Digest-SHA.x86_64
```

Once you run this command your script should be running fine without any error.

Hope that helps. :)